# Can you leave the amount of items in an array unknown?

Tags: c++

Would

> string Example[ ];

be an array with an undefined amount of values?
If so could I import values from a .txt file into it even if I didn't know how many items there are?

Comment: It doesn't even compile...

Comment: No. This is why we have `std::vector`.

Comment: no you cant. Tbh your question is a bit funny, because `string` already can grow in size... If you really want many strings use a `std::vector<string>`

Comment: You can us a `std::vector<string>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: dude how was i supposed to know that. it has to be one of the most broad questions.

Comment: @ChessRobot "_how was i supposed to know that. it has to be one of the most broad questions._" I disagree. One could've searched for "C++ array declaration", and arrived at this page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array , or one could've searched for "C++ array declaration without size", and arrived at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259098/how-to-declare-an-array-without-specific-size . Or, alternatively, one could learn from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), instead of coding randomly.

Answer (score 7):

C++ does not support variable length arrays. Instead, you could use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::string> Example;
Example.push_back("some string");
std::cout << Example.size() << '\n'; // prints 1
```

Vectors can contain as many elements as you like, and are automatically resized when you add new ones.