# How to declare two-dimensional array in class in header file

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to declare a two-dimensional array in my class like so:

```
#pragma once

class Matrix
{
    float elements[][];
};
```

Except this isn't valid. If I get rid of the last two square brackets, it does work though. What do I need to change to be able to declare a two-dimensional array without initializing it?

Comment: You cannot create Variable Length Arrays in C++ (some compilers do allow it for one dimensional arrays, but it's non-standard). Use `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` instead.

Comment: For plain arrays (2D or not) the size has to be known at compilation time. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: If you need plain array, you need to state its size or alternatively use `float **elements;` which behaves very similarly to an array. Another option is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: I would prefer a single `std::vector<float>` for storage like proposed e.g. here: [SO: C++ Matrix Class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/7478597).

Comment: @liaquore What should the size of the array be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ declare an array of arrays without know the size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830197/c-declare-an-array-of-arrays-without-know-the-size)

Comment: If you want a dynamic array you want `std::vector`. If you want a static array you want `std::array`. You never want a C-style array *except* when forced to by some other legacy code (and even then you can usually still use `vector` or `array`).

Comment: "If I get rid of the last two square brackets, it does work though" - No, not really. VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) are *not* supported by standard C++. Some compilers support VLAs as an extension to the language, but that's not portable and you do not want to rely on it (in fact I would recommend you explicitly *disable* non-standard extensions in your compiler).

Comment: If I use std::vector<std::vector<float>> how do I add an element to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You have to use dynamic allocation.
Use `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` instead as @Yksisarvinen said.